# costmap_2d with nothing but a clearing footprint?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-jade, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to set up a costmap_2d initialized to be 100% unknown or obstacles, and have it do nothing except clear grid locations within the footprint.  I don't want to have a static map that is unchangeable, just provide initial values that can be cleared by moving the footprint over them.

As it is now the static map doesn't get altered by the obstacle layer, it preserves it regardless of the footprint moving over it.

Do I need to create a fake sensor that will put an obstacle in every grid location when I want to initialize it?

This is with jade.

*** Update ***

I've tried to publish a point cloud into the obstacle layer that drops a point into every grid location, but even then the footprint is only cleared within the current footprint, if I move the footprint the old obstacle grid points now outside the footprint are restored.

Publishing a single large point cloud that attempts to cover the entire grid (this isn't quite working either, it is only clearing a circle, but more likely that is my fault) also causes the costmap node to issue a huge costmap_update every cycle, even though nothing is changing or getting updated, and it complains about not being able to keep up: `[Map update loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.4570 seconds]`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241649/costmap_2d-with-nothing-but-a-clearing-footprint?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nature of the static layer is that it cannot be changed. You can initialize everything to be unknown using the `track_unknown_space` parameter. http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

My old answer to this didn't get transferred from answers.ros.org but has some valuable information, like the attached image, so copying it over- I'll fix it up to be more complete and make sure it still works with ros noetic next.

Timple96 provided this link though I haven't looked at it closely: https://github.com/nobleo/full_coverage_path_planner/blob/master/nodes/coverage_progress

[image: costmap footprint clearing]

My adapted answers.ros.org answer:

I think the solution will be a custom node that publishes an OccupancyGrid and subscribes to the footprint, and uses an opencv function to draw the footprint onto the grid when it updates and this will get the desired obstacle clearing behavior.

I was able to take a pgm with all black pixels, a static map config with negate: 0, and the obstacle layer has combination_method: 0:

```yaml
plugins:
  - {name: static, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: cleared, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}

cleared:
  track_unknown_space: true
  combination_method: 0
```