# Painting the spots robot visited: in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2, python, robot, python3

I have a robot (let's say it is a simple 2-wheeled+caster wheel diff drive robot). It works as a vacuum cleaner of a sort: moves over the "world", leaving behind a band of "clean carpet". My question is, how can I paint this path that robot covered, in a different color, so it can be easily seen? I would provide my ideas, but I have none: no idea how to do it right. I use ROS2, Python and Gazebo. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the costmap footprint clearing  in https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/75777/costmap-2d-with-nothing-but-a-clearing-footprint - would the the equivalent of that for ros2 work?  (https://answers.ros.org/question/241649/costmap_2d-with-nothing-but-a-clearing-footprint/ has a an image that didn't make it through the answers.ros.org conversion)- It's not in gazebo but it is in ros.